# cv::dnn::Layer::forward does not work on specific layer (python)

Tags: opencv, neural-network, openvino

I'm using the openvino toolkit in python for head position estimation.
I load the network as follows:

```
weights_headpose = 'head-pose-estimation-adas-0001-2018-FP32.bin'
config_headpose = 'head-pose-estimation-adas-0001-2018-FP32.xml'
model_headpose = cv.dnn.readNet(weights_headpose, config_headpose)
```

The following

```
print(model_headpose.getLayerNames())
```

gives:

```
['angle_p_fc', 'angle_r_fc', 'angle_y_fc']
```

When I run:

```
>print(model_headpose.forward('angle_y_fc'))
```

I get a float, as expected; 
BUT when i run

```
print(model_headpose.forward('angle_p_fc'))
```

or

```
print(model_headpose.forward('angle_r_fc'))
```

I get the following error:

```
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.1.0-openvino) C:\jenkins\workspace\OpenCV\OpenVINO\build\opencv\modules\dnn\src\op_inf_engine.cpp:688: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !isInitialized() in function 'cv::dnn::InfEngineBackendNet::initPlugin'
```

Are these layers not initialized? Can someone please help me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you clarify that you are providing an input blob before inference?

Comment: Yes I am. After loading the net, I run ```blob_headpose = cv.dnn.blobFromImage(frame_crop, size=(60, 60), crop=False) ``` and ```model_headpose.setInput(blob_headpose)```. Moreover, running model_headpose.forward() gives the same float as running model_headpose.forward('angle_y_fc')

Comment: Thanks, so issue is like a missing library, you may try to remove/reinstall latest opencv or install openvino and use opencv from the installation which brings the libraries with it. Or please check your environment variables as well if you are into virtual env. I had tried the same and didn't have the issue, I am able to run model_headpose.forward('angle_p_fc') and get values as expected.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that. It took me a while to set everything right to use the opencv from openvino and not the normal opencv-python. Now it uses the openvino one but when I run 'pip list' I only see 'opencv-python'. How can I update the openvino one?

Comment: try to run `setupvars.sh` in `/opt/intel/openvino/bin/setupvars.sh` in terminal and run the python in there to check if working.

Comment: This also does not work. When i run the setupvars.bat and run the python file in command prompt I still get ```print('RRR: ', model_headpose.forward('angle_r_fc'))
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.1.0-openvino) C:\jenkins\workspace\OpenCV\OpenVINO\build\opencv\modules\dnn\src\op_inf_engine.cpp:688: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !isInitialized() in function 'cv::dnn::InfEngineBackendNet::initPlugin'``` As a sidenote: my path is configured so that I can run the openvino demo's without running the setupvars and I changed the path in my PyCharm as well.

Comment: Strange, I can't reproduce the issue to work. You may check `PYTHONPATH` again, make sure your cv2.__version__ is something with 'x.x.x-openvino' . Sorry, can't help further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My question was solved by using `model_headpose.forward(['angle_p_fc', 'angle_r_fc', 'angle_y_fc'])`